# Ckeditor error django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 87, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 568, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 711, in configure_handler
    klass = self.resolve(cname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 394, in resolve
    self.importer(used)
  File "/home/sabo/projects/iDocs/web/django/api/utils/utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from main.models import EnterpriseEntry, Permission
  File "/home/sabo/projects/iDocs/web/django/main/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    from moderators.models import HackerLogin, CompanyPayment
  File "/home/sabo/projects/iDocs/web/django/moderators/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .widgets import CKEditorWidget
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 54, in <module>
    class CKEditorWidget(forms.Textarea):
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 59, in CKEditorWidget
    class Media:
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/widgets.py", line 68, in Media
    static('ckeditor/ckeditor/'),
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/js_asset/js.py", line 14, in static
    if apps.is_installed('django.contrib.staticfiles'):
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 231, in is_installed
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/sabo/projects/envs/idocs/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I cant resolve this problem. I already installed django-ckeditor, added into installed_apps in settings.py like 'ckeditor', and now when I trying to run project I saw this error, It's happened when I added `from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField`
into models.py

and this is my manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "iDocs.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

currently my virtualenv has python2.7 and my django version 1.7

pls help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

INSTALLED_APPS Had an missing comma, that caused this error for me.